# Blockchain.info "Too Many Requests" - Alternative solutions that can be hosted by myself

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, blockchain.info

I'm trying to build out a Bitcoin service that requires me to query address balances and other data. So far I've been just using blockchain.info to do these request, but lately i'm hitting the too many request error. I've looked into alternatives, but many of these just went belly up over the years. Blockchain.info seems to be best long standing one that is free up to a point. Even blockstream.info has a limit.

Is there some type of locally hosted service I can just use it for the same type of query data like blockchain.info? I understand I'll need to install bitcoind and download the entire blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blockstream.info is powered by Esplora, which is open source and reasonably easy to run yourself. You can then query that API as much as you want, with no rate limits. Note that you need quite a bit more disk space than just running Bitcoin Core.

Esplora code repo (front end, with links to back end repo): https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora

Comment: 300gb vps host is quite expensive at about $50 a month. any alternatives for something cheaper to host a public btc node? I dont want to run it off of my home cable internet.

Comment: I know that Luna is being used a lot for bitcoind VPSs. But I'm not sure what the cheapest VPS with large storage is.

Answer (score 0):

You should check https://github.com/janoside/btc-rpc-explorer

BTC RPC Explorer is a simple, database-free self-hosted explorer for the Bitcoin blockchain, driven by RPC calls to your own Bitcoin node. It is easy to run and can be connected to other tools (like ElectrumX) to achieve a full-featured explorer.

Whatever reasons one may have for running a full node (trustlessness, technical curiosity, supporting the network, etc) it's helpful to appreciate the "fullness" of your node. With this explorer, you can explore not just the blockchain database, but also explore the functional capabilities of your own node.

Live demo available at: https://explorer.btc21.org

Answer (score 0):

You can try [my script](https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser) that can convert raw blockchain database to the simple text format with all blockchain blocks and transactions data in it.

Those text files contain all information you need, but balances need to be calculated through calculation of UTXO set from those data in offine mode. No need RPC calls or any of remote API. All processing goes local on your's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Two good options currently are [Esplora](http://github.com/Blockstream/esplora) (as outlined in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/97173/101498)) and [Mempool.space](https://github.com/mempool/mempool).