# API for large number of queries to different addresses every few minutes

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, api, balance, database

I have an application that needs to makes queries to get address balances and transaction data from Bitcoin.

What are some possible solutions to this? It would be great if I didn't have to manage a full node if possible.

Comment: Host your own node, and run some code that allows you to make these queries to it. If you are handling customer funds this is the responsible thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a self-hosted (but low-burden!) instance of [Esplora](http://github.com/Blockstream/esplora).

Blockstream is also exposing an instance for free (at the moment) at [blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info/).

Disclaimer: if you take part of Bitcoin as an economic actor (as an application providing account balances may imply), you should really consider using your own source of truth and self-host the instance. It's just a docker to start and an nginx reverse proxy to set up after all :-).

Comment: i forgot why i couldn't use blockstream.info for whatever technical reason. But is there another alternative? My main thing is checking if there is there a balance at an address and if an address has an outgoing or incoming transaction.

Comment: There are APIs at all most famous explorer, on the top of my head: mempool.space (https://mempool.space/about), blockchair (https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/), blockcypher (https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/). That said, the best one I know of is Esplora's one (even though mempool.space is great for Bisq support). I'd be very interested in knowing what you couldn't use BS.info.

Comment: I'd be interested in setting this up, but have no idea how or where to begin. If you say it's just a docker and nginx reverse proxy, would you know a more detailed guide or tutorial somewhere? Or specifically, what docker images do I need?